# How maven compiler plugin works in JDK 11

Tags: maven, java-11

I am having difficulties understanding HOW maven compiler plugin works **under the hood** post java 8 (i.e. JDK 11).

(I know how to operate it to work with JDK 11 (using `<release>` element), but I am interesting (and confused) as to HOW it works behind the scenes)

When working with pure JDK 11 `javac`, I can give it the `--classpath` argument and have all the jars listed there be treated as Unknown module.

I can also give `javac` the `--module-path` argument, and have all the (non modular) jars appearing there to be treated as Automatic module(s).

But, when working with maven project, using the `maven-compiler-plugin` with JDK 11, how does it compile my code ? are all the dependencies are in the classpath ? or in the module-path ? perhaps both ? what maven uses to distinguish between them ?

I have read the maven-compiler-plugin [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable), that referred me to the [plexus compiler project](http://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-compiler/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/source-repository.html) (and could not find there much to be honest). I expected to be able, eventually, see the actual command line that maven compiler plugin uses when invoking javac for me and its various used arguments. I tried to invoked it with [verbose=true](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#verbose) and did not get anything useful as well..

All in all, I could not find anything useful on that stuff ; All references explains how to operate compiler plugin as a black box, nothing about how it actually works internally. :(

Anyone knows or has a good reference to a proper documentation\explanation on the above ?

**Update:**

Following @khmarbaise comment, `-X` shows a lot of debug information, among it a detailed list of what jars\classes are used in the class-path and which are in the module path.

One strange thing remains though:
I am compiling maven module A which is a java module as well (it has module-info.java file). It seems that A's classes (...\A\target\classes folder) is given to the class-path argument. Any idea why ?

Comment: If don't have a module-info somewhere it will be compiled by using the classpath otherwise it's using the module path...You can use the `-X` and see what is used...what exactly is your question?

Comment: -X did the work ! I can now see exactly which jars are classes are put in the class path and which are in the module path (as well as many other data items that might be relevant in the future).
I will edit my question with this answer. Thanks.

Comment: A thing about your update: In java a module info is `module-info.java` not `module-info.json` ...cause `module-info.java` will be compiled by JDK9+....

Comment: true... I meant module-info.java of course. mistyping.. fixed. :)

One more thing: the dependencies that are placed in the module-path are not java modules and have no module-info.java file at all. So the existence of module-info.java is not the reason for a jar to be placed either in class or module path...

Comment: Just fine.. I just want to be sure. There should be a warning about automatic module names by the maven-compiler-plugin (hopefully you are using the most recent version) if there are jars which are not modules...

Comment: I am using maven 3.6.2, with compiler plugin 3.8.0 ; No warnings were given. It seems that all of my 3rd party dependencies are NOT java modules (they don't have module-info.java) but they all have Automatic-Module-Name entry in their manifest, so I guess that's what relaxes the compiler...

Comment: Yes if they have defined the automatic module name that helps...which is the right way of the library maintainers.